# selenium does not perform click operation

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get information from Kaggle, [This](https://www.kaggle.com/allen-institute-for-ai/CORD-19-research-challenge/tasks?taskId=583) task specific.
I would like to go in selenium over all the solutions.
I have this code:

```
main_window = driver.current_window_handle  
    elements = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-oUaSW").find_elements_by_xpath(".//li")
    for element in elements:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()  
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) 
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//a[@class='KernelViewerContext_KernelTitle-sc-rdaqnd chqxNN']")))
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(main_window)
```

it worked a few times, and then (clicked on the solution, opened the solution in a new tab, and closed this tab when I finished).
But now,

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

does not click well on the element (when clicking on the element, a new tab should be opened)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to iterate over all the solutions in the page.
in order to do so, i need to press on each solution, then a new page is opened, I need to get information from there, close the new page, and do the same for the next solution